# how to use arguments object by js

Tags: javascript

today,i want to get a sum number,but get a wrong number.

```
function fun(a,b,c){
  var l = arguments.length;
  console.log('length'+l);
  for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
    var sum;
    console.log(arguments[i]);
    sum= sum+arguments[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
var p= fun(1,2,3);
console.log(p);
```

p is **'NaN'**

if change the fun(1,2,3) to fun(1,2,3,4,5),is there some differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're not initializing `sum`, so you're adding to `undefined` the first time (`undefined+1` gives `NaN`), then to `NaN`.

Change

```
for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
 var sum;
 console.log(arguments[i]);
 sum= sum+arguments[i];
}
```

to

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
 console.log(arguments[i]);
 sum= sum+arguments[i];
}
```

Note that the `var sum` declaration is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the start of the function.

Comment: @dukegod What do you mean ? There's no closure here.

Comment: if i put var sum declaration inside 'for function',why there console 'NAN'.